# Jquery Mobile Fixed range slider

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I went through the mobile Jquery website and the docs and API but could not find any information appropriate to my requirement

I want something like the slider from this link http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/demos/widgets/sliders/rangeslider.html

However I want fixed denominations like it starts with 100, 500, 1000, 1500 and so on. The slider should first stop at 100 and then move to 500 or 1000 or 1500.

I dont want the denominations between them.

I searched a lot but never had luck, any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `step` attribute for that.

`<input type="range" name="slider-1" id="slider-1" value="100" min="100" max="1500" step="500" />`

Search for "step" on this [page](http://api.jquerymobile.com/slider/). Though the example markup given seems to be missing the actual `step` attribute. Viewing the page source of the working example does reveal it.

Comment: Thanks .. I was missing step.